# OpenShift App deployment methods need some clarifications

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

So I’m having troubles understanding the Openshift app deployment methods as to where should I use the different options when doing

```
Oc new-app —name=test
```

Docker-image=registry.example.com/test:4.7 I know this should be used when you are trying to use an image from the private docker registry but how is that different when you use the oc new-app http://registry.exemple.com/test:4.7

-i test:4.7 http://registry.example.com/test is when you want to create an S2I image with a source code so does that mean that the registry.example.com/test have the git files or/and the Dockerfile I’m a bit confused on this part. Also this can be done via the test:4.7~registry.example.com/test
So here if I did not specify the Image stream it should complain about it but how do I know what kind or type goes well with the app

If I wanted to use an image from the docker-registry that belongs to Openshift, how does it get its images from and what’s its relation with the docker private registry in this example register.example.com so If I wanted to use a new custom docker image with Openshift what’s the approach does it take to have that specific image? Sorry but I’m a bit confused to where images I use come from.

Comment: Have you read the free eBook for OpenShift at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ That may help clear some things up.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton no I have not It looks wonderful and I cannot wait to dive into it, thanks for sharing, I really appreciate your work!